# unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' in iterations through df columns and calculations between dataframe objects

Tags: python

i'm new at python nd maybe the answer to mya question is simple but when i'm trying to loop through my dataframe columns and make some calculations between the objects i get the message unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'.

The code is below:

```
for i in range(0,len(df.columns)):
    if (i%2==1):
        df[i+1]=(df[i]+df[i+1])/2
    else:
        pass
```

basically im trying to create hourly values by taking the mean value and pass it to every column that refers to an hour. and then i will proceed by droping every column that refers to a half an hour value.

the dataframe is like theposted image:  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JELXt.png)

can you please explain why i get this?

thank you in advance!!

Comment: We can't copy your dataframe from your image. Please help us help you by including your dataframe as text as part of your [mre]. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Comment: Try adding some `print` statements (or use a debugger like `pdb++`) to inspect the values of the fields in your expression `df[i]` `df[i+1]` ...the error is telling you one of them is a `str`, so you need to work out which one the unexpected value and why

Comment: From your minimal description of your issue, it seems ```df[i]+df[i+1]``` is evaluating as a string. So it can't be divided. You can try cast it as an int with int(df[i]+df[i+1]) / 2. This may fix your issue

Comment: Thank you all for your immediate feedback! It seems that i had a row with no integers and this caused the problem. Now i dropped it and its fine . Thank you again !

Answer (score 0):

I this data in `df` are string and `df[i]+df[i+1]` also returns a combination of two strings. Maybe a code like the one below will solve your problem:

```py
for i in range(0,len(df.columns)):
    if (i%2==1):
        df[i+1]=(int(df[i])+int(df[i+1]))/2
```